# Code Academy Help - Ruby

Tags: ruby

It is asking me to do the following:

1.
Inside your when "add" block, remove the puts "Added!" statement.

In its place, prompt the user for a movie title. Save the result in a new variable called title. (Your code already has an example of how to do this!)

Next, prompt the user for the rating of the movie. Save that in a new variable called rating.

Add that movie/rating pair to the movies hash and puts a message indicating the pair was added. (No need for to_sym or to_i just yet!)

I am putting this and getting an error that i didn't add  to the movies hash!

```
movies = {
     Batman: 10,
}

puts "What is your favorite movie?"
choice = gets.chomp

case choice
 when 'add' 
     puts "What movie do you want to add?"
      title = gets.chomp

     puts "Whats the rating (1-10)?"
      rating = gets.chomp

     movies[title] = rating
     puts "#{title} has been added with a rating of #{rating}!"

 when "update"
     puts "Updated!"
 when "display"
     puts "Movies!"
 when "delete"
     puts "Deleted!"
 else
     puts "Error!"
end
```

Comment: How do you try to retrieve the film from the hash?

Comment: @Bustikiller I think that will be asked further in the problem but it will not let me get to the next step it says that I am not adding the title and rating to the movie hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was very tempting :) So, I actually logged into codeacademy, found the example and worked on it. Codeacademy only accepts your assignment if the results are as it expects, irrespective of whether its right or not. So I tried varied answers, till I got what codeacademy likes.[image]

Also, in your code, you are creating a hash with symbols when the assignment is for strings. Plus you are not converting your input values to symbols. So, even though your solution may work it will fail on CodeAcademy.

Comment: ...and there is an extra comma after the only row in "movies" hash

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually right

I can confirm that it's a bug from codecademy because my solution is virtually similar and it passed[image: My code is similar to yours]

[image: That shows the code passed]

I faced the same challenge on Codecademy. I think your first option is to ensure the `movies` hash is not altered and it includes **exactly all the movies that were part of the question**. Problem with Codecademy is that it actually checks for return value and not code or logic so sometimes you can getaway by writing code that will pass the submission even when it shouldn't

If that doesn't solve it, alternatively reset the code and type the solution in again and submit. Hopefully this should rectify the problem. I had to do this a couple of times before it worked as codecademy seems to have a couple of bugs. All the best and hope this spolves it

Answer (score 0):

Probably your hash expects symbol keys and you are adding string keys. Try:

```
movies[title.to_sym] = rating
```

Comment: still getting the same error message of: It looks like you didn't add  to the movies hash!

Answer (score 0):

If you added movie "Shinning" with a rating 10 for example, may be Code Academy is expecting the `movies` hash to be equal to `{:Batman=>10, :Shinning=>10}`, but with your code we will have `movies` equal to `{:Batman=>10, "Shinning"=>"10"}`. If that is the case then you have to keep in mind following things:

1. Keys of the hash should be a symbol, not a string (eg. `:Batman`, not `"Batman"`)
2. Value (rating) should be an integer, not a string. (`10`, not `"10"`)

So replace this line:

```
movies[title] = rating
```

with following:

```
movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
```

That's the only explanation I could come up with. However, if that is not the case, then I'd say your code is fine and new key value do get added in the `movies` hash.

Comment: i still get an error I think it must be a bug on codecadmey

Comment: Damn it!! Ya I think its a bug. Cause I can add to the `movies` hash successfully with your code in my machine.